# OleDBParameterCollection only accepts non null values OleDbparmeter type objects

Tags: c#, database, oledbparameter

```
 lala.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Base", OleDbType.SmallInt).Value = textBox15.Text);
 textBox15.Text = reader["@Base"].ToString();
```

The  following error occurs in the first line of code

> OleDBParameterCollection only accepts non null values OleDbparmeter
>   type objects

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new OleDbParameter("@Base", OleDbType.SmallInt).Value = textBox15.Text` is an assignment expression of type `string`. So `lala.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Base", OleDbType.SmallInt).Value = textBox15.Text);` actually is calling `OleDbParameterCollection.Add Method (Object)` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136047(v=vs.110).aspx). And obviously `string` is not a `OleDbParameter` object.

The correct way is to use local variable:

```
var parameter = new OleDbParameter("@Base", OleDbType.SmallInt);
parameter.Value = textBox15.Text;
lala.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```